# Memory Efficient Agglomerative Clustering with Linkage in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, out-of-memory, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I want to cluster 2d points (latitude/longitude) on a map. The number of points is 400K so the input matrix would be 400k x 2.

When I run [scikit-learn's Agglomerative Clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering) I run out of memory and my memory is about 500GB.

```
class sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=2, affinity='euclidean', memory=Memory(cachedir=None), connectivity=None, n_components=None, compute_full_tree='auto', linkage='ward', pooling_func=<function mean at 0x2b8085912398>)[source]
```

I also tried the memory=Memory(cachedir) option with no success. Does anybody have a suggestion (another library or change in the scikit code) so that I can run the clustering algorithm on the data?

I have run the algorithm successfully on small datasets.

Comment: Are you interested in some out-of-the-box solution, or do you want to solve the problem? I'm not sure about scikit-learn, but I can imagine some boosting-based method to solve this issue and I can write it down if you'd want me to.

Comment: @Salvador Dali: for the memory parameter, I have created a directory /tmp/memory_cache and set the memory parameter to memory=Memory('/tmp/memory_cache').

Comment: @FilipMalczak: I'm mostly interested in some out-of-the-box solution but it can be another toolbox in C++ or any other language and I can add it to my pipleline.

Comment: Then sorry, I've got nothing.