# Python: Converting KMeans Centroids to Shapefile for Pixel Classification in Land Cover Analysis

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, geospatial, unsupervised-learning

I'm trying to use KMeans centroids to label/clump pixels for a land cover analysis. I'm hoping to do this only using sklearn and matplotlib. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
kmeans.fit(band_5)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1])
```

The shape of band_5 is (713, 1163), yet from the scatter plot I can tell that the centroid coordinates have values well in excess of that shape.

From  my understanding, the centroids that KMeans provides need to be converted into the correct coordinates and then a shapefile, which would then be used in a supervised process to label/clump pixels.

How do I convert those centroids to the correct coordinates and then export to a shapefile? Also, do I need to create a shapefile?

I tried to adopt some of the code from this post, but I could not get that to work. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_color_quantization.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-color-quantization-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. scikit-learn expects data in columns (think a table in a spreadsheet), so simply passing in an array representing a raster band will actually try and classify the data as if you had 1163 sample points and 713 values (bands) for each sample. Instead you'll need to [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the array, and what kmeans will return will be equivalent to quantile classification of your raster if you're looking at it in something like ArcGIS, with centroids in the range of band minimum value to band maximum value (not in cell coordinates).

   Looking at the example you provide, they have a three band jpeg, which the reshape into three long columns:

```py
image_array = np.reshape(china, (w * h, d))
```

2. If you need to have spatially constrained pixels then you have two choices: choose a connectivity constrained cluster method such as [Agglomerative Clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering) or [Affinity Propagation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation), and look at adding the normalised cell coordinates to your sample-set, e.g.:

```py
xs, ys = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(0, 1, 1163), # x
    np.linspace(0, 1, 713), # y
)
data_with_coordinates = np.column_stack([
    band_5.flatten(),
    xs.flatten(),
    ys.flatten()
])

# And on with the clustering
```

3. Once you've done the clustering with scikit-learn, assuming you use `fit_predict` you'll get a label back for each value by cluster, and you can reshape back to the original shape of the band to plot the clustered results.

```py
labels = classifier.fit_predict(data_with_coordinates)
plt.imshow(labels.reshape(band_5.shape)
```

Do you actually need the cluster centroids given you have labelled points? And do you need them in real world spatial coordinates? If yes, then you need to be looking at the [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) and the `affine` methods to transform from map coordinates to array coordinates and vice versa. And then look into [fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona) to write the points to a shapefile.

Comment: thank you very much for the above. I found it very helpful. For now I don't need those centroids in real world coordinates. I thought I needed them to help label my pictures, but based on your feedback that is not the case. I'm trying to get the clustering methods to work, but my kernal keeps dieing. My computer has a memory of 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, which I think of as sufficient given the size of the image. Do you find that these two algorithms take up a lot of memory?

Comment: @byron They tend to, yes, but I would have thought that was more than enough memory for a basic classification. Did you compile the library yourself or are you using a packaged distribution? (and are you using a *nix box or windows?)

Comment: sorry for the slow reply. I'm on a Mac Book and I'm using Anaconda. I've conda install all libraries that did not come as a part of the package. I tried using the memory parameter, but that too did not work. Similar to this other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293459/memory-efficient-agglomerative-clustering-with-linkage-in-python